# Update the view with javascript without duplicate code

Tags: php, jquery, rendering

I have a php application that prints a list of "blocks" to a page. a block includes date, time, title and some other information.

The user needs to be able to add a new "block" to the page, and i'd like the new block to appear in the list of the existing blocks without refreshing the page.

At the moment, i'm doing this with jquery. the user adds a new block, and then jquery inserts a new DOM element, which works fine.

THE PROBLEM: Doing this means that a "block" is rendered in two different ways. One way is with php, when the list is initially printed. the other way is with Jquery, when a new block is added.

Having these two different renders means that whenever i want to change the way a block looks, or add some new field to it, i have to update two different things, the php block and the jquery block.

how can php and jquery to use the same code, to render an individual block?

Comment: Use the same CSS for both.

Comment: Use a CSS class to apply same styling to both blocks.

Comment: Have your PHP code render an empty block inside a `template` element, so that your JS code can “clone” the structure from there …?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code sample it is hard to give you any real advice. But in general you have a PHP solution which will consist of main PHP script and then a snippet which outputs only a single block. The snippet can be included in a loop with passed values for generating of the main page and later can be same snippet called without any values via AJAX and inserted into DOM. Or second option is to use jQuery function .clone() (https://api.jquery.com/clone/). which can clone the block you want but you will still need to clear all the values, if that is what you want. Or eventually you can include one block with no values and hide it with CSS, and once cloned just change its display from none to block or whatever display property it needs to have.

Comment: Those are two great options, thank you! Regarding the first option: what would i pass back with AJAX? would it be straight up html?

Comment: yes just echo pure HTML code of element you want and append after last block or wherever you want it to place